# AnyLogic Measure time in the system for each arrival stream

Tags: anylogic

I have a flow chart like below.
[image: Current flow chart]

my current tmE_SystemA measured time in the system for a customer, regardless of their arrival stream. However, I also would like to know the time for a customer in the system for each arrival stream.

I tried to add 3 more Time Measure End before the current tmE_SystemA and each measure for one tmS_A. But it will gives me error when customer from other streams reach to the new Time Measure End (e.g. when customer from customerArrival_A2 reached tmE_A1 it will show error, saying that this agent not pass through corresponding Time Measure Start.)

So how can I properly measure the time for each arrival stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `timeMeasureStart` and `timeMeasureEnd` blocks, you can just add variables inside your Customer agent called `startTime`, `endTime` and `cycleTime` of type double.

Then, at endService, you can type `agent.cycleTime=agent.endTime-agent.startTime;`. You will have the time in system for each agent.

[image]

Comment: Make that "variables" and not "parameters", though ;)

Comment: Sorry I am new to AnyLogic, could you please show me how to add those variables

Comment: @Tony, added a screenshot to my answer above.